# hashes mismatch when installing from docker file -'pkgs dont match the hashes from req file'

Tags: docker, hash, pip, package-managers

I have dockerfile that installs from requirements.txt file. When installing librosa lib it pulled many other needed libs, when installing pycparser i got this error:

```
 Downloading pycparser-2.20-py2.py3-none-any.whl (112 kB)
ERROR: THESE PACKAGES DO NOT MATCH THE HASHES FROM THE REQUIREMENTS FILE. If you have updated the package versions, please update the hashes. Otherwise, examine the package contents carefully; someone 
may have tampered with them.
    torch from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8c/5d/faf0d8ac260c7f1eda7d063001c137da5223be1c137658384d2d45dcd0d5/torch-1.6.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=5357873e243bcfa804c32dc341f564e9a4c12addfc9baae4ee857fcc09a0a216 (from -r requirements.txt (line 4)):
        Expected sha256 5357873e243bcfa804c32dc341f564e9a4c12addfc9baae4ee857fcc09a0a216
             Got        eb3c7b3621d64e9d9955ec0546729291338556d4ee8ccbf347169f574816f089
```

what's the problem with hashes? I did not indicate any hashes or ids in my reqs file.

my requirements file:

```
flask
pydub
scipy
torch
numpy
librosa
```

dockerfile:

```
FROM voice

RUN mkdir -p ./voice_flask/d
WORKDIR /voice_flask/d
COPY . /voice_flask/d

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD ["python", "server.py"]
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to install the packages fresh using `--no-cache-dir`

```
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt --no-cache-dir
```

see this [Issue](https://github.com/MycroftAI/mycroft-precise/issues/79)